# Comparing 2 Dates One is jquery Object and other is in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, date

I am trying to compare two dates, one is in text box written as `YYYY-MM-DD` and other is jquery Datepicker instance

I am calling the function with a custom wrapper function

```
datePicker('#edd', {onSelect: function(str, obj){ check_if_edd_less_OD(str, obj); }});
```

and below is the JS function to compare dates

```
function check_if_edd_less_OD(s, o) {

    console.clear();

    var eddDate = new Date();
    eddDate.setDate(o.selectedDay);
    eddDate.setMonth(o.selectedMonth);
    eddDate.setYear(o.selectedYear);

    orderDate = $('#orderdate').val().split('-');

    console.log(orderDate);


    var odDate = new Date();
    odDate.setDate(parseInt(orderDate[2], 10));
    odDate.setMonth(parseInt(orderDate[1], 10));
    odDate.setYear(parseInt(orderDate[0], 10));


    console.log(eddDate);
    console.log(odDate);


    if (odDate.getTime() < eddDate.getTime()) {
        console.log('You shall Pass');
    } else {

        console.log('You shall NOT Pass');
    }


}
```

as of today, the orderdate input is set to 2013-03-07, if I select 5 APR 2013 from datepicker it dont work

following is the output of console

```
["2013", "03", "07"]
Date {Fri Apr 05 2013 16:55:23 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)}
Date {Sun Apr 07 2013 16:55:23 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)}
You shall NOT Pass
```

as you can see  `console.log(eddDate);` is giving correct output but `console.log(odDate);` is giving me 7th April 2013.

**Question:** Why this is such a behavior?

Comment: *jQuery `Date` object*??? What's that?

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect datepicker instance. I have fixed that in question

Comment: In that documentation, I can't see reference to .selectedDay or .selectedMonth, what happens if you run console.log(o.selectedMonth)?

Comment: Shouldn't you just call `datepicker.getDate()`?

Comment: i need to compare it with other date in textbox

Comment: @Jodes it give me current month number starting from 0 if today is march it will return 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The month counting of [`Date` objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) is zero-based (January:0, …, April:3). Not sure what format that `o.selectedMonth` is in, but the parsed YYY-MM-DD date should be changed to

```
odDate.setMonth(parseInt(orderDate[1], 10)-1);
```

Btw, you don't need to call `getTime()` before comparing two `Date` objects against each other, they will automatically be casted to that number.

Comment: thank you for the answer, `o.selectedMonth` return integer. For `getTime()` I will check that as well.

Comment: Of course that will be a number. But is it zerobased (0-11) or onebased (1-12)?

Comment: oh sorry.. i didnt mentioned that to you, I had mentioned that in comments to question. well its 0-11 zero based